# regex - test user input for various combinations

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I would like to have a regex that can capture some certain combinations for four words provided by the user. The words are separated by comma or space only.

possible words:

1. none
2. combine
3. online
4. store

Possible combinations:
If none is present then nothing else must exist in the user input.
If online or store are present (1 or both) then combine must exist and vice versa.

Here are some examples:

- none (catch)
- none combine (do not catch)
- combine online (catch)
- combine (do not `enter code here`catch)
- combine online store (catch)
- store online (do not catch) (because combine is not present)
- store store (do not catch)

My regex so far [Regex try](https://regex101.com/r/gCRHVO/1)
`^(?:none|combine|online|store| |,)+$`
But this can only catch a simple combination of all those 4 words.It does not catch if none is present or for duplicates such as store store.

This is in a while loop in bash until the user gives the right input.

```
read -p "Please provide with the geos that were successfully modeled (Please provide the geos separated with space or comma. e.g.: \'combine online\') " user_input2

while [[ $(echo ${user_input2,,} | grep -P -e '^(?:none|combine|online|store| |,)+$' | wc -l) -lt 1 ]]; do
read -p "Please adhere to the instructions and provide a correct input ('combine[ ,]store[ ,]online'): " user_input2
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gm` regex modifiers with the following regex pattern:

```
^(?=(?:(?:none|combine|online|store)(?:\s|$))+$)(?!(?:combine.*combine|online.*online|store.*store))(none$|(?!.*none)(?=.*online|.*store).*combine.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/z58QrH/1

---

*Depends on the regex engine you use, you might need to adjust the syntax of this regex solution accordingly.*